# Close JFrame in actionPerformed-method (JFrame is private static void createGUI())

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have copied most of my Code from an oracle-example, so I think at least the code I did not add should be correct and I don´t like to change that. But in the oracle-code I can not implement this line to properly close my JFrame: `frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

```
private static void createGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NameChooser");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createGUI();
        }
    });
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
    if (e.getSource()==skipButton){
        frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)); WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)); // does not work ofc
    }
}
```

How can I close my JFrame in the actionPerformed-method without destroying this correct way of opening a JFrame ?

Or is this oracle-code just suitable for examples and not for real applications ?

Comment: I cannot access my instance of JFrame (frame) nor JFrame in my actionPerformed-method

Comment: I cannot access my instance of JFrame (frame) nor JFrame in my actionPerformed-method ---> then don't extends JFrame, create a local variable for this Object, btw this is possible, but local variable is correct way

Comment: So make `frame` an instance field

Comment: The follwing  works: `frame2 = frame;` in createGUI-method and then in my actionPerformed: `frame2.dispose();` But did you meant that and is this okay to do ?

Comment: `private static void createGUI() {` that should probably not be **`static`**.  The same goes for most attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `frame` an instance field like this:

```
private static JFrame frame;

private static void createGUI()
{
    frame = new JFrame( "NameChooser" );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why should I use .equals instead of == ? But anyway your idea looks very clean so I´ll go with that, thank you !

Comment: OK, so in this situation you can use == sorry for misleading.